# Show in a group $G$ that $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a $.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Show in a group $G$ that $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a $.

Solution:

Note that by definition $(a^{-1})^{-1}$ and $a$ are both inverse elements of $a^{-1}$. Since in a group each element has a unique inverse, we can conclude that $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$.

I will now prove that in a group inverse elements are unique.

Suppose $b,c \in G$ such that $ba = e = ab$ and $ca = e = ac$ That is to say, $b$ and $c$ are both inverse elements of $a$ where $e$ is the identity of the group $G$.

Then we have $b = be = b(ac) = (ba)c = ec = c$

Therefore $b=c$ and inverse elements are unique.

Comment: This is fine. ${} {} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof looks fine. However, since you make a point of both mentioning and proving that each element has a unique inverse I would advise you to make precise what you mean when you write $a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

I too agree that our OP Mathematical Mushroom's argument is without flaw.

Here is a one-liner, given that $e \in G$ is a group identity element:

$(a^{-1})^{-1} = (a^{-1})^{-1}e = (a^{-1})^{-1}(a^{-1}a) = ((a^{-1})^{-1}a^{-1})a = ea = a$

$OE\Delta.$